# AactionMailer configuration without authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have to send e-mails from a Rails application, and am trying to do so with ActionMailer. The mail administrator created a new account for the purpose that requires no authentication; I am able to send messages with this new account with `msmtp` using a configuration like (in `~/.msmtprc`)

```
account myapp
auth off
host mailserver.domain
port 25
from myapp@domain
user myapp@domain
password
```

In the `development.rb` file I introduced a similar configuration:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp 

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   address:              'mailserver.domain',
   from:                 'myapp@domain',
   port:                 25,
   domain:               'domain',
   authentication:       'off',
   user_name:            'myapp@domain',
   password:             '',
   enable_starttls_auto: false  }

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

But whenever a mailing method is invoked I get the following exception:

```
   (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 387ms

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  app/models/user.rb:28:in `send_admin_mail'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

I imagine something is wrong or missing in the `development.rb` file, but I have no idea what it may be. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**: Following [eugen's suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794971/aactionmailer-configuration-without-authentication#comment44009026_27794971) I found that at execution time `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` does not contain the correct settings; in particular, `address` is pointing to `localhost` instead of pointing to the mail server:

```
=> "{:address=>\"localhost\", 
     :port=>25, 
     :domain=>\"localhost.localdomain\", 
     :user_name=>nil, 
     :password=>nil, 
     :authentication=>nil, 
     :enable_starttls_auto=>true}"
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: `from` is not used in this context, and since you're not using authentication, `user_name`, `password` and `authentication` are also not needed. The rest of the configuration seems fine, so make sure the server name specified in `address` is correct, and the SMTP server is actually reachable from the application server - the ECONNREFUSED looks like a network issue.

Comment: Hi removed the parameters you indicate: `from`, `user_name`, `password` and `authentication`, but I still get the same error. I am trying this out from my development environment, from where the email server is reachable. I am able to send e-mail from the command line with `msmtp` using this same server.

Comment: Try logging `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings.inspect` in the `send_admin_mail` and check if the settings are actually what you expect them to be. If they are, I still think it's a network issue.

Comment: As you suggest, `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` is not what I expect it to be at execution time (check the update to the question) Any idea why?

Comment: Check the initializers, you might have `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` set up differently somewhere. Failing that, try setting `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` in `development.rb`, instead of `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`

Comment: Eugen: I initially used the suggestion to directly set up `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` in `development.rb` to work around this problem. But after a system restart things started functioning as expected. In any case, your leads were very useful, if you wish to collect them in an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: A system restart seems kind of drastic - you probably just needed to restart the rails application server. Remember to do that after every configuration or initializer change.

Comment: Yes Eugen, that could have been the case, I might have missed a rails restart after one of your suggestions. The system was restarted for different reasons though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your configuration has some problems. Just like the the 'from:' key, it should not be placed in smtp_settings. As for other possible problems, please refer [RubyonRails.guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Hope to do some help.